# Difference between Pre-insert,Preinsert and Pre-insert_nowait triggers in oracle forms

Tags: forms, oracle

In My FMB file in oracle forms at the block level i am having three triggers PRE-INSERT,PREINSERT,PRE-INSERT_NOWAIT..i wanted to know the difference of these triggers and when these triggers will execute, i searched the net and oracle forms online help but did not found any information related to these triggers.I am having confusion with the last two,Are these triggers have any significance? or it just the dead code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK there's only the `PRE-INSERT` trigger, I haven't heard of any `PREINSERT` or `PRE-INSERT_NOWAIT` triggers in Forms. Where did you see these? Or maybe they are custom triggers?

Comment: @Kemp:I think you are right, They may be custom triggers but there should be a way when these triggers fire, can oracle forms fire custom triggers? correct me if am wrong. Thanks

Comment: If they're custom triggers, you won't find anything useful in the Forms help or online. They'll be called using the `execute_trigger` builtin.

Comment: @Kemp:I did not find usage of `execute_trigger` in my whole code, can i say this is dead code?

Comment: I'd say so, if you have indeed made an exhaustive search. Note that calls may be made not just in the FMB but also in a MMB or PLL.